# Connect RDS from lambda serverless

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-rds, aws-cloudformation

I have created a server-less instance using Cloud Formation. I am not trying to connect to an existing RDS. I have seen templates for creating RDS instances but not for connecting to existing one. I really don't want to create one, I want to use an existing one.

My first guess and attempt was to create a AWS::RDS::DBSecurityGroup but that seems to apply to setting the security for an RDS instance created from them template. I just want to connect to an RDS that is already there.

I tried just adding the IP to the white list but the IP changes on each request so that did not work.

I tried changing the policy to add full RDS access, but this seems to only allow for management, not for accessing the DB.

```
    "Policies": [ 
        "AWSLambdaFullAccess",
        "AmazonRDSFullAccess"
    ],
```

Started with code from here: 
https://carlos.mendible.com/2017/07/04/deploy-your-asp-net-core-web-api-to-aws-lambda/

Comment: Did you place the lambda inside vpc and in a subnet where rds is accessible?

Comment: There is no VPC, it is serverless.  No the lambda and the RDS are not on the same subnet.  In fact my longer term plan is to have one central RDS multiple lambda instances in different zone accessing it so I intentionally am testing from different zones.

Answer (score 0):

To access RDS from Lambda, Lambda needs to be attached to the VPC and also placed in a subnet which has access to RDS.

You can place Lambda in different Availability Zones still meeting the above requirement.

Note: If RDS is placed in a private subnet and if your Lambda also needs to access external services outside VPC, you need to look at setting up NatGateway for it.